# how exactly returning a variable with or without *this differs | this isn't questions about *this pointer | correctness

Tags: c++, binary-tree

I have a code class below which represents a node in a binary tree:

//btnode class

```
class btnode {
public:
    btnode(int data): m_info(data), m_left(nullptr), m_right (nullptr) {}

    btnode* get_left_btnode ()  { return this->m_left; }
    btnode* get_right_btnode () { return this->m_right; }
    int get_data () { return this->m_info;}
private:
    int m_info;
    btnode* m_left;
    btnode* m_right;
};
```

I've a questions! how would it matter if i had members functions like follows:

```
    btnode* get_left_btnode ()  { return m_left; }
    btnode* get_right_btnode () { return m_right; }
    int get_data () { return m_info;}
```

any other suggestion of how efficiently write this treenode will be helpful

Comment: Code review question are more suitable on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: Those getter functions are useless. Make the members public!

Comment: @DeiDei thanks. only i've already realised that. after when i faced issue of pointing an updated left child node to newly added node. guess (lvalue problem).

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking if the explicit dereferencing of `this` is needed (`this->`), then the answer is No. It's completely optional and makes no difference in this case.

There are situations where `this->` makes a difference though. For example if you have a local variable named the same as a member variable, then you'd need `this->` to refer to the member (but a better solution would be to name your variables uniquely).

Comment: can you please write a small example where it will impact the correctness of the result and will differ. Scope: the question. thanks for the answer though

Comment: It makes a difference e.g. here: `void set_info(int m_info) { this->m_info = m_info };` (without `this` the member `m_info` is hidden) - Now this is obviously not needed since you wouldn't name the parameter `m_info` but you get the point.

Comment: @Max Langhof I'm quite well aware of that. I said only that it does not matter *here* with the 3 get functions OP asked about. Of course there are situations where `this->` makes a difference.

Comment: I meant to answer @Amaresh's comment of "small example where it matters". Sorry for the confusion!